# App pop Up saying "... Would like to access your (Camera, location, photos, etc)"

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Using Xamarin Ios. in Apps theres usually a pop up on launch that says "(app name) Would like to access your location" or photos, or things along these lines. i couldnt find any information on how to implement this, or even what this confirmation/permission process is called. can someone point me in the right direction? it would be much appreciated

Comment: I've removed your `visual-studio` tag because this is not a question about the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99717/how-to-give-permission-for-camera-used-in-ios-app-with-xamarin-forms check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application needs to invoke some function that involves user privacy,suah as Camera,Contacts andLocation Services. You will be prompted for authorization by the system.

You should add items in `Info.plist` As shown in the following image.For example if you want to use Location Services. Otherwise it will be rejected when you want to upload your application to APP Store.
[image]

There also some other privacies.Here is a document link for you to referring to:[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy)