# App crash when denied location permission in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, permissions, location

i need to have location in my app and app got crash when user denied the location permission by clicking "Don't Allow". i got "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException". but once i again start again even on that time the permission is denied its not crashing . in android its working fine .Do i need to update permission plugin or change in info.Plist?
here is my code

```
          var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
                {
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Location denied", "app needs access to location for this operation.", "OK");
                }

                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
                status = results[Permission.Location];
            }
            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                  // do something
            }
            else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
            {
                  // Crash when user denied permission 
            }
```

Comment: Share the crash log as well.

Comment: @RoHaN there is no log its simply got crash with showing Main.Cs file with crash

Comment: @RoHaN Unhandled Exception:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
The thread 0x4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Surround your code with a try/catch block. You may get more information on this exception.

Comment: Also check inner exception. Like this:
===============
`try
{
    // code block causing TargetInvocationException
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e.InnerException != null)
    {
     string msg = e.InnerException.Message;
    }
}`
===============

Answer (score 1):

You should add items in Info.plist

Refer to the link :[App pop Up saying "... Would like to access your (Camera, location, photos, etc)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196453/app-pop-up-saying-would-like-to-access-your-camera-location-photos-etc/52199232#52199232)

and document :[Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy)

Comment: i have already given permission for location in my info.Plist

Answer (score 0):

Check your MainActivity OnRequestPermissionsResult(). Comment one by one another receivers of permissions and run. You will find the culprit. Good luck!